# Excel Interop read only filtered rows

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

**Original non filtered table**

[image: Original non filtered table]

**Filtered table**

[image]

I am trying to read a .xlsx file using Interop.Excel. The **xlRange** variable seems to have a strange behavior, when I set it to display only filtered cells(visible):

`Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);`

**Debugging:**

*When table is not filtered:*

**xlRange.Count: 15** //Total amount of elements in the table

**rowCount: 5**  //Thats including header

*When table is filtered:*

**xlRange.Count: 9** //This is correct

**rowCount: 1**  //This should be 3 (including header)

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Example.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

//iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
//excel is not zero based!!
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        //new line
        if (j == 1)
            Console.Write("\r\n");

        //write the value to the console
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
            Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
    }
}
```

Having in mind that xlRange.Count is 9 I should be able to access all 3 rows manually disregarding the rowCount variable but xlRange seems to be the same original non filtered range:

```
Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[1, 1]);//Writes ID, Correct
Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[2, 1]);//Writes 1, Should be 2
Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[3, 1]);//Writes 2, Should be 4
Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[4, 1]);//Writes 3, Should not be able to acces this element element at all because xlRange.Count is 9
```

Comment: Great question, well written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect what you want is to iterate the `.Rows` property instead of being literal about the row/column.  Something like this:

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in xlRange.Rows)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        //write the value to the console
        if (row.Cells[1, j] != null && row.Cells[1, j].Value2 != null)
            Console.Write(row.Cells[1, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

When you specify a row, column within a range I suspect it will go to that exact row (relative to the range).

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... :)