# Possible to read filtered row data?

Tags: c#, xlsx, epplus

##### Scenario

1. Having an existing Excel XLSX file with a table and data.
2. This table is filtered. E.g. it would have 5 rows without a filter and is currently filtered to only have 3 rows visible.
3. I want to use EPPlus to read that very filtered 10 rows from the XLSX file.

This is how the table could look like when being unfiltered:

[image]

And this is how the table could look like when being filtered:

[image]

##### Question

Is it possible to get only those filtered rows via EPPlus in C#?

I've searched through various issues in the EPPlus repository as well as through Google in general and did not find one single similar question/answer.

It seems that [this is possible via PIA and Excel Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54479899/107625), but I want to do it without any Office dependency.

Comment: You can read each cell's or column's hidden status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also asked the question on EPPlus' GitHub page and got [a working answer](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/issues/602#issuecomment-1050578547):

One has to check if the `ExcelRow.Hidden` property is false to get only the unfiltered, visible rows.

Example:

```cs
if (!worksheet.Rows[rowNumber].Hidden)
{
    // Process visible, unfiltered row.
}
```